# c#: adding two strings

Tags: c#

I am doing:

```
html = new WebClient().DownloadString(
        "http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=" + biocompany);
```

and i am getting the error:

```
Error   1   Operator '&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string'
and 'string'
```

but I am not even using the & !

Please help!

Comment: What is `biocompany`? And are you *absolutely* sure that is the error line? If you comment out that line does it work fine? Note also that `WebClient` is `IDisposable`, so (unrelated) there should be a `using` in there too.

Comment: Post more code, there's nothing invalid about the snippet you posted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code you've posted executes successfully.  Your problem lies elsewhere.

The compiler error you're getting will indicate exactly what line is failing, and it's not the line you've posted.  Look to that to get started.

Make sure you've got your quotes correct.  The following line, for instance, will cause exactly the error you're reporting:

```
html = new WebClient().DownloadString(
    "http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome"&"ie=UTF-8&q=" + biocompany);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try @ before first quote (") like this:

```
html = new WebClient().DownloadString(@"http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=" + biocompany);
```